# How to remove transparency in KDE without disabling all desktop effects?

Tags: kde, themes, transparency

I don't understand the hype for transparency. From a usability standpoint I see no argument whatsoever that transparency should enhance your productivity or improve your workflow. Any element on top of another one is inevitabily more ditracting and takes longer to grasp than a single clean and well designed element. True, it's much more complex to design consistent and meaningful elements, panels, symbols and windows without any transparency.

Still I want to remove transparency from KDE 4.7 without disabling desktop effects alltogether. Since I don't find an opaque theme I would like to use (hints are welcome!) I want to disable the transparency within existing themes. How to do that?

thx for reading, p.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:**

"...but my problem is not to disable transparent windows, but panels, widgets, notifications, tooltip-previews, menues and stuff..."

**A:**

Earlier: [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels/70730#70730)

Comment: Thx! So it will be a quite cumbersome process to remove those transparencies by replacing all the relevant SVG-files with homemade versions and adapt with every update ... I guess at this point that seems the only way to go ...

Answer (score 5):

Go to: System Settings->Desktop Effects->All Effects and scroll down to "Translucency" or search from the search bar which is there and just disable it and hit Apply. - that's for disabling Opacity while u move the window.

If your window is transparent even if u don't move it, just press Alt+F3 on the selected window and go to: Opacity->100%

Comment: thx for your hint but my problem is not to disable transparent windows, but panels, widgets, notifications, tooltip-previews, menues and stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an opaque theme: Big-Blue

I just installed it and it has removed transparency from the "task manager" bar. Legibility recovered!!! 
 --->   [image: screenshot of translucent panel]

( To install for KDE 4.13:  go to: System Settings--> "Desktop Theme" ;  click "Get New Themes...";  type 'Big Blue' into the search box;   click install;    close the dialogue;  select that theme; click apply. Yeah! )