# Shortcuts and transparency in Kubuntu Oneiric

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, shortcuts, transparency

Is there a way to set in Kubuntu Oneiric keyboard shortcuts to:

1. Show the desktop (used to be called "toggle showing desktop" in old versions of Kubuntu but now seems to be gone from the preferences).
2. Run specific programs (e.g. Winkey+e will start Dolphin, Winkey+t will start Konsole, etc.)

Also, is there a way to disable the transparency of the bottom panel? I don't want to completely disable transparency, only to prevent the panel to change its looks every time my wall changes (I use slideshow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KDE plasma desktop: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma

1) Do you have the plasma widget / plasmoid "Show Desktop" on your panel ?

With it you could add the shortcut

[image]

2) K > Applications > Help >Application Manuals > Settings > Menu Editor

ie. with the Dolphin; Menu Editor - Advanced tab: Current shortcut key

[image]

> is there a way to disable the transparency of the bottom panel?

Earlier: [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels)