# How to personalize KDE menu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, architecture, personalization

I would like to personalize the KDE menu. I would like to add the Ubuntu version and architecture on top of the menu

Example: Kubuntu 12.04 64bit Precise Pangolin

How to do it?

That's the menu I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KDE Menu / Kickoff**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff:

> Kickoff is the default application launcher of the Plasma desktop...

The Kickoff is a plasma widget. The plasma theme can be altered.

**Plasma Themes**

Earlier: [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels/)

The KDE plasma objects are using the svg images. You could edit the images with a svg capable picture editor (Inkscape et. al.). The Kickoff ( http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Plasma/Theme#Current_Theme_Elements ) has the

> /kickoff.svgz :
>   background for the kickoff launcher, needs a frame,
>   with the prefix 'plain'

and

> /branding.svgz :
>
> a little KDE logo that can be customized by distributors as a branding
>   element. Contains a single element called brilliant

The Kubuntu is using:

[image]

/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/apps/desktoptheme/default/widgets/branding.svgz

/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/apps/desktoptheme/oxygen/widgets/branding.svgz

You could edit those or the plasma widgets C++ source.

Comment: Great answer!  great technical and complete answer... thanks!

Comment: @null You should upvote it then.