# Remove panel shadow in KDE 4.8+

Tags: kubuntu, kde, panel

It seems that panel shadow is somehow hardcoded in KDE 4 and devs do not have any plans to change it and/or make it customizable. So, what I'm actually asking is some kind of hack (if there is any) which will remove the shadow of the panel in KDE 4.x completely (but without need to disable all desktop effects in the process).

Possible application: When a user wants a completely transparent panel, no top/bottom borders at all, the shadow is completely out of place and destroys the experience.

[image: As requested by user26687, the image shows the panel shadow.]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Could you**

Could you show an example picture ?

How did you make/test it ?

**At here**

Editing the neon-plasma-glow-by-FRUiT plasma/desktop theme /widgets/panel-background.svgz picture file. Disabling the object fill -> full transparent panel.

[image]

I can't see panel shadows.

**Take 2**

KDE documents:

- http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/TweakingPlasma
- http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Theme

From the Kubuntuforums:

- http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56120-Customize-plasma-desktop-theme

The original Air theme (1), Transparent (2), Without the shadow (3).

[image]

1) Copying the default plasma theme (Air) from the /usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/default to the ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/transparent .

2) Editing the ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/transparent/metadata.desktop. Changing the theme name to the Transparent

3) Editing the ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/transparent/translucent/widgets/panel-background.svgz

[image]

4) Changing the Fill from the Linear gradient to the No Paint. The result is a transparent panel with the shadow (2)

[image]

5) Removing the shadow. Picking the shadow elements and deleting them. The result is a transparent panel without the shadow (3)

[image]

6) If you want to use the partial/mini panel edit the mini elements.  Change the Fill to the No Paint.

[image]

The panel svg image is a bit bare....

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Still, I do see the shadow, as the image shows (I used the same theme you mentioned). Note: if I disable desktop effects and enable them again, the shadow does disappear. But if I change desktop theme, the shadow appears again.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the result is still the same (tested on Netrunner, which is basically Kubuntu, with prop nVidia graphics driver, and Debian with nouveau graphics driver, both with KDE 4.8.5). Also, changing panel-background.svgz from "transparent/translucent/widgets" dir doesn't have any visible effect whatsoever; only the one in "transparent/widgets" does. Note that I emptied cache (~/.kde/cache) prior to applying transparent desktop theme every time, just in case. Will test it some more.

Comment: OK, killing plasma-desktop might just make the difference. Will see if it holds water :-)

Comment: For KDE 5.x, the theme is located at /usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/default/.